# Windows Phone 7.1 BackgroundAudioPlayer error codes (0x803a000a)

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

Is there a resource for BackgroundAudioPlayer error codes?

I receive an error code of 0x803a000a when calling Play(). Is it known what this error code is?

I can't find a good list of the error codes and their meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected override void OnError(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, Exception error, bool isFatal)
{
    if (isFatal)
    {
        player.Track = null;
        switch (error.Message)
        {
            case "-2147012889":
                //MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to streaming server.");
                break;
            case "-2147012696":
                MessageBox.Show("No available network connection.");
                break;
            case "-1072889830":
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot find stream.");
                break;
            case "-2147467259":
                //MessageBox.Show("Error. Try again later.");
                break;
        }
        Abort();
    }
    else
    {
        player.Track = null;
        switch (error.Message)
        {
            case "-2147012889":
                //MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to streaming server.");
                break;
            case "-2147012696":
                //MessageBox.Show("No available network connection.");
                break;
            case "-1072889830":
                //MessageBox.Show("Cannot find stream.");
                break;
            case "-2147467259":
                //MessageBox.Show("Error. Try again later.");
                break;
        }
        NotifyComplete();
    }

}
```

- “-2147012889”    80072EE7    Can’t find the server (e.g. phone is in flight mode)
- “-2147012696”    80072FA8    No available network connection
- "-1072889830”    C00D001A    Can’t find media file (e.g. the MP3 file you were pointing to is no longer on the server)
- “-2147467259”    80004005    Non-specific error code

Hope that helps.